# Using constructors and getMethods to exchange variables between classes outside the main method

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to java. My goal is to update a variable with information from another class. To do this I tried using a constructor and a getMethod. I set a variable with user input the main method to class 'L'. Then I need to also tell class 'C' that it needs to update a variable with the same information. Therefore in class 'C' I use *var* =  L.getMethod(). Now I try print *var* in the main method. It only prints the default value I set an not the user input which updates this.

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Location L = new Location();
       Cast C = new Cast();

       L.setLocation("BEACH");
       System.out.println(L.getLocation());

       C.setLoc();
       System.out.println(C.getLoc());
       }
```

In the first print statement it prints BEACH as it should. The second print statement prints HOME which is the default. Why is this happening and how do I get the 'Cast' class to update itself with the information from the 'Location' class.

further relevant code:

```
public class Cast {
   Location L = new Location();

   private String location;

   Cast(){
    location = "";
   }

   public void setLoc(){
   this.location = L.getLocation();
   }

   public String getLoc(){
   return location;
   }
}
```

Note that location is made in a constructor in the Location class and I used a toString() method to return it. Does this affect it?

```
public class Location {
    private String location;
    Location(){
         location = "HOME";
    }
    public void setLocation(String loc){
         location = loc;
    }
    public String getLocation(){
         return location.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location you are creating and setting a new value to is different than the Location you are using inside of Cast

If your main method is located in Cast, You could try:

```
   //L.setLocation("BEACH");
     C.L.setLocation("BEACH");
```

-- update --

Your biggest issue is with your `Location` class. It is creating a double pointer in `Cast`, and then you are also adding a String variable in Cast for location.

If you just get rid of your Location class and just use the location String variable in Cast, it will solve your problem here.